# Embedding modeless dialogs as child window with Windows API

Tags: c, winapi, dialog, childwindow, createwindow

I know, there must be a way to embed an (modeless) dialog as child of a window created with `CreateWindow`. In my case I want to embed them into an scroll-able container window, whereby this container windows it self is a child of the main window (see picture).

[image: Embedded Dialogs]

The first problem that I encounter is, that I still want be able to use TAB keys and other dialog specific navigation. But how?

My message loop:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    if (IsDialogMessage(msg.hwnd, &msg)) continue;
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** For testing purpose I modified the loop:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    if (IsEmbeddedDialogWindow(msg.hwnd)) {
        if (IsDialogMessage(msg.hwnd, &msg)) continue;
    }
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    if (IsScrollableContainerWindow(msg.hwnd)) {
        if (IsDialogMessage(msg.hwnd, &msg)) continue;
    }
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

More information how to make it the right way can be found here: [Using the TAB key to navigate in non-dialogs, redux](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131009-00/?p=2983)

With this message loop, nothing happens if I want to enter some dialog texts as if the message is not handled. If `IsDialogMessage` is removed, I can enter some text into an edit control in one of the embedded dialogs, however dialog navigation doesn't work as intended. Of course, `WS_TABSTOP` style is set for dialog child controls.

The scroll-able container is created with `CreateWindowEx` with styles 
`WS_CHILD, WS_VISIBLE, WS_VSCROLL, WS_TABSTOP, WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` and dialogs are created as children of this container.

```
    HWND hWndContainer = GroupBarPanelCreate(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP, WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, hWndMain, 0, 0, 400, 400);
    GROUPBAR_PANEL* GroupBarPanel = (GROUPBAR_PANEL*) GetWindowLongPtr(hWndContainer, 0);
    // Test embedding dialogs
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        HWND hWndDlg = CreateDialogParam(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWndContainer, About, 0);
        GroupBarPanelInternalAddLast(GroupBarPanel, hWndChild, hWndDlg, nullptr);
    }
```

My `GroupBarPanelInternalAddLast` modify modeless dialog styles by removing caption and borders, and ensures that `WS_CHILD`, `WS_VISIBLE` and `WS_TABSTOP` is set (`SetWindowLong(hWndDlg, GWL_STYLE, ...)`). (Also tested `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` style) With `SetParent(hWndDlg, hWndContainer)` modeless dialogs parent is changed.

[image: Working Demo]

So what am I missing here? As I found out, neither the container window procedure nor the embedded (for testing purpose subclassed) dialog procedure almost never gets `WM_SETFOCUS` or `WM_KILLFOCUS` messages for example, but why that?

**Solution:** Calling IsDialogMessage for the top level window.

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg)) {
        if (IsDialogMessage(hWndTopLevel, &msg)) {
            continue;
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: `IsDialogMessage` needs to be passed the `HWND` of the candidate dialog, not the window the message is targeted at.

Comment: Well, it should be given the `HWND` of the window that has the `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` style, and which is the parent of the other dialogs.

Comment: On creation you need to manually set the input focus, otherwise keyboard navigation won't work. I'm not entirely convinced that this can be made to work reliably. Why aren't you creating regular windows instead?

Comment: @JonathanPotter It also didn't work. I tested both, IsDialogMessage was only called for the container window, and I tested also to call it for the dialog windows. Both didn't work.

Comment: Shot in the dark: do the dialogs have `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` too?

Comment: Yes I also tried to add this `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` style to dialog windows, without any changes in the described behavior.

Comment: Er oh, your `IsDialogMessage()` call is still wrong. You don't want to call `IsDialogMessage()` only when the message is sent to the dialog. You want to call it for **all** messages, passing the HWND of the topmost window that contains the sub-dialogs — in your case, of the Win32AppDemo1 window.

Comment: (Also [`TranslateAccelerator()` goes before `IsDialogMessage()`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050408-41/?p=35943).)

Comment: @andlabs Thanks a lot, passing the top level window really worked. So I'm a bit confused now since in the www almost all information about how to call this `IsDialogMessage` seems to be wrong.

Comment: Can you link the references you've found? I'd like to see them as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using `IsDialogMessage()` correctly, and you said you learned from some bad tutorials. I don't know which tutorials you saw, so I can't tell you what they got wrong; all I can do is say how to use it correctly.

`IsDialogMessage()` takes two parameters: the message itself, and the window handle of the **toplevel window**. This bit in bold is the important part: the `IsDialogMessage()` function needs to know which dialog to work with in the event of tab navigation or Enter/Esc handling.

You don't want to pass `msg.hwnd`; that's the control itself.

And in the case of nested child dialogs like you have here, you don't want to pass in the child dialog's handle; that would confine `IsDialogMessage()` to that dialog.

So in your screenshot, you want to pass in the handle of the main window, that is, the window called `Win32ApiDemo1`.

Also make sure all the child dialogs and your custom expander control have `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` so tab navigation can recurse.

Comment: Precisely, which window handles in this example should have `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` extended style? I tried setting it for every window, yet it doesn't recurse.